# how do write a laravel query in reverse order

Tags: mysql, laravel

how do write a laravel query in reverse order

```
SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY -id DESC
```

This works but want to transfer this in laravel query

How do write in this way please guide

```
return $this->belongsToMany('something...')->where('actove', '=', 1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->with(['users']);
```

Comment: $orders = Orders::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Do you have model called Orders ?

Comment: The model name should be singular, so it should be called `Order`. If you change that, what kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This code could work

```
return $this->belongsToMany('something...')->where('active', '=', 1)->oldest('id')->with(['users']);
```